# ListView ItemsSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView with 3 columns:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ParamName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="109" Margin="10,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="281">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="60"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="60"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="156"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Currently, I have set `ParamName` as my ItemsSource, which will obviously not achieve the desired result this way.

In my ViewModel, I have ObservableCollections for each Column (`ParamName` for Name, `ParamType` for Type and `ParamContent` for Content). Those ObservableCollections are correctly filled and I am able to receive their data through the Binding, but I cannot fill the columns with their respective data.

I have thought of certain possible solutions, but none of them seem to work. What would be the best approach for this problem?

Here's how it looks like (left) and how it should look like (right):

[image: How it is]
[image: How it should be]

Naming them after their Types might be a little bit confusing.

Comment: Do you have three (3) Collections? Why?
You bind only one Collection as I understand - and all tree columns have same values? Try to change ParamNames to see if it is so.
If my suggestion is right - then try to make one collection of complex type, containing all your values: ObservableCollection<MyRow>, where MyRow is a class with needed properties.

Comment: @Shwed_Berlin Yeah, that's the problem I have. I have 3 different collections and I would like to bind one collection to each column.

Comment: try to make one collection of complex type, containing all your values: ObservableCollection<MyRow>, where MyRow is a class with needed properties.
_P.S. Sorry, have troubles with editing my comment :)_

Comment: @Shwed_Berlin Given I have this collection, how would the data be correctly presented in the ListView?

Comment: read my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three Collections, but only one is binded. So all columns have same value.
Try to create one Collection containing all you need:

```
ObservableCollection<MyRow>
```

where `MyRow` is a Class or Struct with Properties you need.

If you already have these Collections - try to concatenate it to one major Collection and tell the GridColumns which Properties you wish to bind to each Column, but I'm not sure if it's possible with ObservableCollections - what if they have different length?

And you can still create your own Collection from these three - just parse it...